# How can I to add an array of `TextView` data into an existing text view?

Tags: android, textview

How can I to add an array of `TextView` data  into an existing text view? I tried the following code:

```
TextView tvArrQuestion[]=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textparse);
```

...but I get this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `TextView` to `TextView[]`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do solve like ths:

---

first take a string append all the text arraydata to it.

---

```
String txt="";
for(int i=0;i<tvArrQuestion.length();i++)
{
     txt=txt+tvArrQuestion[i].getText().toString();

}
```

than you can set it to textview

lets take textview tv so code is:

```
tv.setText(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant give like that in ur code. Place ur code as:

```
TextView tvArrQuestion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textparse);
```

and give

```
tvArrQuestion.setText(your array data);
```

Comment: in my code i used like this tvArrQuestion[intLstLength] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textparse);
   tvArrQuestion[intLstLength].setText(objDataSet.getQuestion().get(intLstLength)); so i need to declare it as tvArrQuestion[]

Comment: otherwise u give : List<TextView> tvArrQuestion = new ArrayList<TextView>; for(int i = 0; i < intLstLength; i++) { tvArrQuestion[i].setText(objDataSet.getQuestion().get(i)); }

Answer (score 0):

Another Concept is below As this type u also add Text view

```
   LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);


    TextView name[];
    TextView website[];
    TextView category[];


     for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
        name[i] = new TextView(this);
        name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
        website[i] = new TextView(this);
        website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
        category[i] = new TextView(this);
        category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));
        layout.addView(name[i]);
        layout.addView(website[i]);
        layout.addView(category[i]);

   }
```

Comment: actualy in u r code we r displaying the array contents in a newly created layout, but i need to display it in existing layout(in existing text view) can u pls tell me how to do that,am brand new to android so unable to find

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using existing Layout

Textview name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  String txt="";
  for(int i=0;i

}
name.setText(txt);